# why doesn't the memcached protocol specify an encoding for text?

Tags: memcached

the subject says it all, why didn't the creators of memcached specify a text encoding as part the protocol?

I've seen a mix of ASCII and UTF-8 implementations and obviously the latter lets you write data which the former would fail to decode.

Answer (score 0):

The memcached [ASCII protocol](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt) specifies that you can store "*a chunk of arbitrary 8-bit data*", i.e. from the point of view of the server everything is a binary object. It is up to the client library to decide how to encode the data to be stored.

In your case, if you access memcached with libraries which use different encodings for strings, you may want to use some kind of binary safe intermediate representation such as Base64. Of course, the ideal would be to fix the client instead.